# Best way to apply inheritance and code reuse

Tags: java, typescript, oop

I have a question regarding the best way to structure code for reuse with inheritance in cases, where some methods in the base class does not make sense in the inheriting class.
I think this is a general OOP issue and not only peculair to TypeScript...

So basically, in some form of pseudo code, the issue is similar to this:

class BaseClass
        makesSenseForA
        makesSsenseForA
        ....
        doesnotMakeSenseForA
        doesnotMakeSenseForA
        ....

How then to have a `Class A` inherit `BaseClass`. Just direct inheritance means that `Class A`  would have member methods that does not really make sense.

Not using inheritance means the things that code would be duplicated in both `BaseClass` and `Class A`

Moving  the `makesSenseForA` methods to an external class and have both `BaseClass` and it's children class depend on this extracted class (ie using composition) does not work in this particular scenario, because the extracted class should actually be seen as A `BaseClass`.

How really is the best way to handle this kind of OOP modeling situation?

EDIT:
For lack of better example, it is like trying to model `Human` and `Cyborg` - this two would share a ton loads of similar implementation and hence first thought might be to have `Cyborg` extends `Human`...

But also there would be a ton of implementation that `Human` has that `Cyborg` should not have.

Doing away with inheritance means those similar functionality would have to be duplicated in `Human` and Cyborg`.

And composition also does not work, because if you extract those implementation that are similar into a separate object, that object, and it's method would have a property of `Human`, and hence should be seen as a `Human` in our modelling.

Comment: Are those `doesNotMakeSense` methods fitted for another inherited class B or are they only fitted in `BaseClass`? Are those methods public?

Comment: Regarding your edit, I think your model has a flawn. A `Human`is an `Humanoid`. A `Cyborg` also could be an `Humanoid`. But it's weird to say a `Humanoid`is a kind of `Human`.

Comment: Ok, I will remove humanoid from the example...I think it could have the unfortunate repercussion of causing confusion

Comment: no, that's good. That's what you need: `Humanoid`can be a class that encapsulate the common behaviour/methods of both `Human` and `Cyborg`. Problem solved!

Comment: I thought about such approach, but what I am cautious about is a situation where I end up with a long hierarchy of classes. Sure in the example it is clear cut `Humanoid/Human/Cyborg`, but in the real life modelling, complications like `SuperHumanoid/FemalHuman/MaleHuman/?Human/GenuisCyborg` would quickly enter the picture, and the complexity of keeping track of what method in base class should not leak to child class would explode!!!

Comment: Just try see it the other way round. When you have a class `Humanoid`, do you really need the subclasses `Human` and `Cyborg`? What if `Humanoid` has a property `Controller` with the subclasses `Brain` and `Computer` and a property `Material` with the values `Flesh` and `Steel`? Of course, classes `FemaleHuman` and `MaleHuman` are obsolete, as `Humanoid` can have a `Gender` property (even humans nowadays want more than two possible values, so having a gender for the `Cyborg` is no problem). A common OOP mistake is forget that the *purpose* of the classes should drive the abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it indeed is a common issue. But your example isn't a very accurate reference to inheritance. We mostly use inheritance not due to common functions. Common functions, to reuse them, can be written as utilities/utility classes. You inherit a class when it is basically a sub-type of the parent class, and we create interfaces for things that are not actual objects but a type. For example:

- Interface: Animal
- Class: Tiger implements Animal
- Class: Goat implements Animal

Note than `Animal` as such cannot be objectified. Now even though a lot of the functionalities of both classes `Goat` and `Tiger` will be common, but neither should extend the other, since a method `hunt()` will not make sense to the Goat class, and `graze()` won't make sense for `Tiger`. For that, we use interfaces. Now, to move common functions in the same class, you can further break this modularity as:

- class Carnivore extends Animal
- class Herbivore extends Animal

No brownie points for guessing what `Goat` and `Tiger` will implement now. In case, there are common functions, that you cannot for some reason write in the `Animal` class, you can write them as a utility. Suppose you have a robotic goat, that has a lot of common functionalities with an actual goat, you do not `extend Goat`, but move common functions as a utility, say `GoatUtilities`.

**Edit:** Someone pointed out that utility classes aren't exactly OOP but procedural... But they can definitely compliment your classes to help them follow OOP the correct way. That's why they're "Utility" classes. So, here's the point that got missed, what I tried to point out basically was how inheritance was being misinterpreted / misused in the given example that was in a way leading to the issue that kinda violated OOP principles. Having a viable object oriented design doesn't imply that you shouldn't use utility classes, because the objective is to apply inhertence and code reuse.

Comment: This is a good answer:

Do not rush to create a base class whenever you have common functions, make sure your type is a subtype.

Comment: Utility classes are not object oriented. I point this out only because the question is tagged as `oop`. Utility classes are a procedural programming construct.

Comment: Yes, you're right... But they can definitely compliment your classes to help them follow OOP the correct way. That's why they're "Utility" classes. What I tried to point out basically was how inhertence was being misinterpreted / misused in the given example that was in a way leading to the issue that kinda violated OOP principles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making the method private it will only be usable in that class. If you make it protected it will be usable in all sub-classes too. So the methods that make no sense in `Class A` should be private, the others should be protected or public.

In java you can learn about this further [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_modifiers.asp).

Comment: what if you need those method to be public in `BaseClass`?

Comment: Private methods does not work in this scenario, because those methods actually make sense when public on `BaseClass`, they don't just make sense when `Class A` inherits them.

Comment: Then the whole structure is a bit messed up. Can you give me an example. Maybe you could make a `BaseClass` and then a `Human` and a `Cyborg` class. So the `BaseClass` can have the methods that contains what a `Human` and the `Cyborg` needs and no more.